# "If" statement - Order of validation of objects?

Tags: c#

Simple question about the order of an IF statement in C#.NET

```
if (Company !=null && Company.ID > 0)
{
}
```

Does C# work from left to right, and therefore make the check on Company.ID valid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Essentially, yes.

The `if` statement expects a boolean operator within the parentheses to determine evaluation of the next statement.

Using the `&&` operator, if the first boolean check `Company !=null` is false, it will statement returning false, and not execute the other (`Company.ID > 0`).

Also (for reference), using the `||` operator will return true after the first statement if it is true and not evaluate the second.

Comment: It will short-circuit because of `&&`, has nothing to do with the `if`. I figure I'd comment this to be complete, otherwise, +1.

Comment: Thanks for the "reference". That was the point I was interested in.

Comment: Just for everyone's reference, the link above is to C++, not C#. I'm looking currently for C#, thought it might be helpful for others to know this =)

Answer (score 6):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28VS.71%29.aspx):

> The conditional-AND operator (&&) performs a logical-AND of its bool operands, but only evaluates its second operand if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it does.  You can prove this by substituting the conditions for function calls:

```
if (myfunc() && myfunc2())
{
  console.writeline("Success");
}

...

bool myfunc()
{
  console.writeline("func1");
  return false;
}
bool myfunc2()
{
  console.writeline("func2");
  return true;
}
```

Should output:

```
func1
Success
```

Answer (score 3):

The && operator is a so-called short-circuit operator. It tests the statements from left to right and stops testing once one of the tests fails. If you want every test to be run, use the & operator.

More info can be found [here](http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2006/08/02/short-circuit-operators-in-c/)

Answer (score 1):

In addition, if you for some reason want both expressions to be evaluated, and not shortcutted, use a single "&" instead of a double.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes

Marginally longer answer: that form of the and will use short circuit evaluation so if Company is null then it won't perform the second check.

Answer (score 0):

If you want performance, make it into one "if" with multiple conditions.  Assuming Performance Profiler is accurate, the latter approach below is twice as fast. In this case, it evaluated as False most of the time, so take into account the probability each of your conditionals will end the process.

```
   int m0;
   for (m0=0; m0<100000000; m0++) // slower
   {
    if (m0==1) continue;
    if (m0==2) continue;
    if (m0==3) continue;
    if (m0==4) continue;
   }
   for (m0=0; m0<100000000; m0++)  // faster
   {
    if (m0==1 || m0==2 || m0==3 || m0==4) continue;
   }
```